# How to update a texture raw content by applying to it an OpenGL Filter?

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, egl

I m under android. I have a texture ID and I want to update the content of this texture (basically I want to apply to this texture an OpenGL filter). Note: I don't want to apply the OpenGL filter on each draw of the texture, I want to change the raw content of the texture (by applying to it an OpenGL filter)

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean with 'OpenGL filter'? There are the texture sampling filters (`GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER`,`GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER`,etc.). Applying those to a texture makes no sense, because they define how data is obtained when sampling the texture in the areas between texel centers.
However, if you want to apply some Gaussian filter (or any other convolution filter) to a texture, using the OpenGL(ES) pipeline, you can use a concept called 'Render to Texture'. The idea is to render into a texture object instead of the 'visible' default framebuffer.

In OpenGL(ES) this is can be done using a Framebuffer Objekt (FBO for short):

1. Create the FBO ([glGenFramebuffers](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glGenFramebuffers.xml))
2. Bind the FBO ([glBindFramebuffer](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glBindFramebuffer.xml))
3. Attach the target texture to the FBO ([glFramebufferTexture2D](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glFramebufferTexture2D.xml))
4. (Check if the FBO is complete (good to go) ([glCheckFramebufferStatus](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glCheckFramebufferStatus.xml))
5. Set the Viewport to match your FBO's texture's resolution

Now you render into the target texture. Simply draw a screenfilling quad with your input texture and the result will end up in the target texture.

To go back to the default framebuffer call `glBindFramebuffer(0)`

Some Notes:

- You shall not read from the texture you're writing to! So use two different texture objects for input and target texture!
- In this setup you wont have a depth or stencil buffer! If you need one, add one using a [Renderbuffer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Renderbuffer_Object) or attach a depth texture to the FBO.

Comment: thanks! by OpenGL filter, I mean EGL filter (a filter that does contrast, blur, etc.)